# Madison Island Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to download Magento complete with the Madison Island theme, if it is possible.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Did we manage to answer your problem ? If so, could you please accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Madison island is basically the `rwd/default` theme that comes by default with Magento 1.9.

If you also need the content (products,categories,cms...) I suggest you install the sample data.

Comment: @Lorraine please mark the answer as accepted if that solved your problem

Answer (score 3):

The Madison Island is the basic/default theme as Digital Pianism mentioned, I also recommend using the sample data to get it.

After that this could be helpful for further styling

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html

Comment: Thank you I have downloaded Magento it didn't have the Madison Island content.  I appreciate the Magento guide.